# Apache: restrict access to specific subdirectory, based on referer?

Tags: apache

I want to allow access to certain folders for visitors coming from specific sites ONLY, otherwise redirect or restrict the traffic with Apache.

In these examples (not working) the idea is to allow access to the /test/ subdirectory only for those visitors coming from "validreferersite.com". I've been trying with these without success:

```
<Location /test/>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'validreferersite.com'">
Redirect / http://www.anothersite.com/
</If>
</Location>
```

Neither this (using .htaccess on my restricted folder):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?validreferersite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)test(/|$) - [F,NC]
```

--

FYI currently I am using this on my Nginx based server (no redirection, just 403).

I need its equivalent for Apache:

```
location /test/ {       
 valid_referers blocked server_names validreferersite.com *.validreferersite.com 
             if ($invalid_referer) {
     return   403;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Own answer: didn't find out an exact solution, but as a workaround you can use .htaccess on the folder you want to "protect".

**This code below will protect all .html files inside the current folder from all visitors who are NOT coming from validreferersite.com**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://validreferersite.com
RewriteRule \.html$ - [L,F]
```